# Laravel - DB:raw

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to set this query in Laravel and I believe that DB:Raw is the best alterntive, how can I set this query in Eloquent or as DB:raw?

```
SELECT      PROP_TYPE,
            concat(round(avg( prop_exclusive = 'Exclusiva' ) * 100, 0),'%') as Exclusiva,
            concat(round(avg( prop_exclusive = 'No Exclusiva' ) * 100, 0),'%') as No_Exclusiva
FROM        PROPERTIES
WHERE       PROP_MARKET_CENTER = 'KW' AND
            PROP_EXCLUSIVE IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY    PROP_TYPE
ORDER BY    PROP_TYPE ASC
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume yo have a `Property.php` model similar to this.

```
class Property extends Model
{
    $table = 'PROPERTIES';
}
```

From here just use `DB::raw()` for the selects and the rest is standard usage of the Eloquent QueryBuilder.

```
$properties = Property::select(
        'PROP_TYPE',
        DB::raw("concat(round(avg( prop_exclusive = 'Exclusiva' ) * 100, 0),'%') as Exclusiva"),
        DB::raw("concat(round(avg( prop_exclusive = 'No Exclusiva' ) * 100, 0),'%') as No_Exclusiva")
    )
    ->where('PROP_MARKET_CENTER', 'KW')
    ->whereNotNull('PROP_EXCLUSIVE')
    ->groupBy('PROP_TYPE')
    ->orderBy('PROP_TYPE', 'asc');
```